# How display a matrix in MFC C++

Tags: c++, mfc, matrix, grid

I have a matrix of integers in a variable and I want to know how can I display it and what controler I've to use for in MFC ?

Comment: CListCtrl with the style of Report comes to mind first

Answer (score 2):

For more advanced formatting options, I always use a grid control for displaying matrix data; more specifically, the [CGridCtrl from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8/MFC-Grid-control-2-27). It's pretty old but works very well.